# update UITableViewCell from content of another UITableViewCell in same table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a UITableViewController configured with a static table made up of 5 custom cells (this is meant to be a form).

- cell 0 captures a date
- cell 1 is a UICollectionView filled with icons representing activities. depending on which activity is selected, one of many custom UITableViewCell are loaded on the fly in cell 2 .
- cell 2 can be simple (just a slider), a textfield or more complex (a UITableView)
- cell 3 has a textfield to capture a description.
- cell 4 is for additional notes

so far everything is working as expected. I select an activity in cell 1, the matching XIB is loaded in cell 2, data is captured, comment added etc and form is saved. Where i am challenged is in the case where based on the the input in cell 2, i would like to update cell 3 automatically. i got it working but i feel it isn't elegant or clean so would appreciate others input. in

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// main table cells pseudo code
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        <#code#>
    case 1:
       // dequeue collectionviewcell
    case 2:
      // dequeue the relevant uitableviewcell based on selected cell in the uicollectionview
        switch selectedIndexPath.row {
            case 2:
                <#code#>
            default:
                <#code#>
        }
    case 3:
      // handle the description field
    default:
        <#code#>
}
```

a specific activity will load "eventFlushMedTableViewCell" which is meant to display a list of meds in a uitableview. based on which meds I select, i would like to take the name of the meds and put them in cell 3.

```
case 2:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventFlushMedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! eventFlushMedTableViewCell
    // fill the meds table with the list of Rx meds
    cell.medsArray = medListArray.filter { $0.medRx == 1}.map {return $0.medName}

    // return the selected values from the table
    cell.returnValue = { selectedIndexPaths in
        let indexList = selectedIndexPaths.map { $0.row }
        self.selectedMedsName = indexList.map {cell.medsArray[$0]}
        // force a reload of cell 3
        let myIndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 3, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [myIndexPath], with: .none)
    }
    return cell
```

and cell 3 in the main table is dequeued and configured

```
case 3:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventDescriptionCell", for: indexPath) as! eventDescriptionCell

    if !selectedMedsName.isEmpty {
        cell.eventDescriptionTextField.text = selectedMedsName.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
```

something tells me the closure around (**cell.returnValue {...}**) in **case 2:**, even though it is working, isn't the right way of doing this... any advice ?
thanks

Comment: A better way than an extra array is to keep the `isSelected` state of the cell in the data model. And a lot of `map` expressions in `cellForRow` could be unnecessarily expensive, too.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion.. i haven't paid much attention to performance/profiling the app but will do and cleanup those expensive bits (i might have gone overboard on the map/filter/reduce :) . as for your suggestion re. data model (i presume for the table), is it a reference to the selectedMedsName and build this in the data model ? having difficulty following.

Comment: The model is the data source array, it contains the data for each row.

Comment: "*something tells me*" What, specifically, is that something? Gut feelings aren't something that can be objectively dealt with.

Comment: i consider myself a hobbyist and this is a personal App i am writing not one that i plan on putting on the App Store. In my learning journey i would like to write clean code or follow best practices and some of the OO concepts are still challenging. In this instance, while it is working as is, my instinct tells me there is a better way and i will give the delegate approach a good try.

Comment: being new to StackOverflow, i am learning the hard way that my question was closed since it is "opinion based"... nevertheless i appreciate those who offered an opinion. what i don't understand is why the "downvote" ? from the help centre  "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post" !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way of approaching this would be to create a custom delegate.
Let's name it ActivityCellDelegate. You can create it like this:

```
protocol ActivityCellDelegate: class {
    func activitySelected(_ activity: Activity)
}
```

We use 'class' so we can make the delegate 'weak' reference. Otherwise XCode will cause trouble :).

Using an enum to represent different activities is a nice touch. You could also use a String as an identifier or an Int as an id.

```
enum Activity {
    case activity1
    case activity2
    ...
}
```

Add a delegate property to the TableViewCell:

```
weak var cellDelegate: ActivityCellDelegate?
```

Then, when dequeuing a cell, you set it's delegate to self `cell.cellDelegate = self`, and make the controller that has tableView as a subview conform to the delegate protocol.

```
extension TableViewController: ActivityCellDelegate {
    
    func activitySelected(_ activity: Activity) {
        //...in here you would probably reload the third cell in the table view. You could add an additional property in the ViewController in order to know which activity is currently selected.
    }
}
```

In the end, when user selects a CollectionViewCell to choose an activity in `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` you should call the delegate method:

```
delegate?.activitySelected(.activity1)
```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. i will give it a try and in the process tidy up my code